# How to find out if asp.net mvc 5 project has web api?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've started working on almost finished project, done in asp.net mvc 5, what's the quickest way to find out if there is web api implemented and how can I find out if there is an api endpoint somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer isn't clear.

1. If you have in solution only ASP.NET MVC 5 project which is used
   only as client then in web.config or in concrete implementations of
   http client should be endpoints on your Web API endpoint.
2. If there's not endpoint in `web.config` and you can't find
   implementation of getting the data from endpoint - try find it use
   global search in Visual Studio with "`http://`", "`https://`",
   "`.com`" and etc. keywords.
3. Also you can start the project and show requests and responses with
   fiddler after you make some clicks in UI. Also you can do it on server if the project's already deployed.

I hope something will help.

Comment: thing is, project is quite big and there's some frontend done via razor and jquery, my task is to implement a couple new features in angular 2 and I'm not sure if there's an api endpoint... 

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: There may not be endpoints. If the project badly structured then client code may communicated directly to controllers from razor pages.

Comment: there's a wcf service which converts to json objects

Comment: yeah, I think that's It